# How to split column value and check value is present using sql where query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, split

I need to check one value in column has semicolon separated values, but i don't want to use like query instead is there any options by split and check the column values

My table is like

```
ID      Values
1    RCI Argentine;Brazil;RCM Poland
2    Brazil;Germany
3    Australia; Poland
4    RCM Poland;Germany
5    RCI Argentine;Brazil;Germany;Italy
```

My requirement i need to check value '`Poland`' exist in this table, when i use like query it pulls up this output

```
ID      Values
1    RCI Argentine;Brazil;RCM Poland
3    Australia; Poland
4    RCM Poland;Germany
```

But my actual output should be

```
ID      Values
3    Australia; Poland
```

If my value is '`RCM Poland`' it should be

```
ID      Values
1    RCI Argentine;Brazil;RCM Poland
4    RCM Poland;Germany
```

Is there any other options to split and check the columns?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: The best option would be to redesign your database

Comment: @MotoGP sql server 2008

Comment: `';' + values + ';' like '%;RCM Poland;%'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should never store more than one value in a column which **violates** the `First Normal form`.

Storing more than one value with a delimiter makes the parsing of data very difficult just like your case. So consider changing your database design.

To answer your question with current table structure you need a split string function(Not recommended)

```
SELECT [ID],
       [Values]
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply (SELECT *
                    FROM   Splitstrings([values], ';')) cs
WHERE  cs.SPLIT_VAL = ' Poland'
```

Here is a article about split string functions **[Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)**

Comment: i am facing Invalid object name 'Splitstrings'.

Comment: ofcourse you need to create a split string function from the link i provided

Answer (score 0):

You can store that field like: ;Australia;Poland;
and where value like '%;Poland;%'
If you don't like this, just use MotoGP's solution :v

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
select * from yourtbl where ';'+[values]+';' like '%;yourval;%'
```